# Android App Publishing Upgrade: Same Key But Dev Console disagrees!

Tags: android, publishing, signing

I am trying to publish an upgrade to my app in Android Market. I am using the same key and alias as before (I have only one key and a single alias). But I get the error "The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version.". This is not the first time I am uploading upgrades. Never had problems before.

The only difference I have this time is I added a new sub-package to the project. My base package is "in.vasanth.android.droidsave". I added a package "in.vasanth.android.droidsave.db". Does adding a package affect the upgrade? Or did I some how mess up my key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are uploading an exported .apk file, not the one that is normally built in the project's `bin` directory. Adding a sub-package won't affect anything as long as you haven't changed the package name for the overall application in the manifest file.

Comment: I just double checked. I exported the apk to a separate folder unrelated to the project and then uploaded it. I have not even moved the key since I created it. Only thing I can think of is I backed it up using Carbonite. It does not show any changes to the file.

Comment: I've heard of people having this problem if the original .apk file was signed with _both_ the debug certificate and the publisher's certificate. (That is, the original signing was done by running the signing tool against the .apk file in the bin directory.) You may be able to determine that by examining the apk currently on the market. If that's what happened, you'll have to continue signing in the same way.

Comment: I am really sorry. I feel so stupid. I actually had two keys. Just was trying the wrong key. As usual the error was with between the keyboard and the chair.